# Simple Jquery Countdown Problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Please see code below. Timer works, but minutes decreases faster than the seconds. Minutes shouldn't be decreasing before seconds reaches 0. How do I make it so that minutes decreases AFTER seconds reach 0?

```js
(function($) {
  function timer(time, update, complete) {
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
      var now = time - (new Date().getTime() - start);
      if (now <= 0) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        complete();
      } else update(Math.floor(now / 1000));
    }, 0);
  }


  timer(
    300000,
    function(timeleft) {
      var min = Math.round(timeleft / 60);
      var sec = Math.round(timeleft / 5);

      $('.timer').html(min + " minutes " + sec + " seconds");
    }
  );
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class=timer></span>
```

Comment: I think if you do `Math.floor(now / 200)` it closer, but cant say it the `100%` correct count rate

Comment: Editing that in the base function just multiples the time involved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set your timer say at **one** minute, **you cannot start at 59 seconds**.
Use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`

Calculate seconds using `timeInSeconds % 60`
Don't set timers (`setTimeout` in our case) to `0`. Use something performance-friendly like `1000 / 60`

```js
(function($) {

  /**
   * timer - Countdown seconds from a provided ms value
   * @param {Number} time - time in MS
   * @param {function} update - Callback - returns time in seconds
   * @param {function} complete - Callback - returns time in seconds on complete
   */
  function timer(time, update, complete) {

    var start = +new Date(),
      timeout, now, sec;

    (function tick() {

      now = time - (+new Date() - start);
      sec = Math.ceil(now / 1000);

      if (now <= 0) {
        // STOP ticking!
        clearTimeout(timeout);  
        // COMPLETE - Execute callback function (if provided)
        if (complete && typeof complete === "function") complete(sec);
      } else {
        timeout = setTimeout(tick, 1000 / 60); // Recursive ticks...
      }

      // UPDATE - Execute callback function (if provided)
      if (update && typeof update === "function") update(sec);

    })(); // start ticking... (Thank you Timeout!)

  }

  timer(
    60000,
    function(timeInSeconds) {
      var min = Math.floor(timeInSeconds / 60),
          sec = timeInSeconds % 60;
      $('.timer').html(min + " minutes " + sec + " seconds");
    }, function(timeInSeconds) {
      console.log("DONE! " + timeInSeconds);
    }
  );

})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class=timer></span>
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to do. I just stumbled upon the setTimeout as you solved the problem. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: @Kris you're welcome :) hope I did not made any bugs my-self ;)

Answer (score -1):

I think your problem is about Math.round(), what about using ceil instead of it ?

EDIT : Maybe you also want substract by 1 because when timeleft is 59 or less , minute become still 1.

```js
(function($) {
  function timer(time, update, complete) {
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
      var now = time - (new Date().getTime() - start);
      if (now <= 0) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        complete();
      } else update(Math.floor(now / 1000));
    }, 0);
  }


  timer(
    300000,
    function(timeleft) {
      var min = Math.ceil(timeleft / 60 ) - 1;
      var sec = Math.round(timeleft / 5);

      $('.timer').html(min + " minutes " + sec + " seconds");
    }
  );
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class=timer></span>
```

Comment: Works more accurately but still the same problem. I think splicing the time in the activation function (timer(300000) is problematic. Perhaps need to separate variables in the actual function for the two so they synchronize. Ie 0 seconds makes minutes go down vs 48 seconds for a minute down.

Comment: Hmm. I understand your problem now, i edit my code :). Multply by 5 will work .

Comment: Not what I was aiming for, want both minutes and seconds to go down but not one before the other.

Comment: Ok, but i conflict about 5 second duration for every second go down, is it necessary ? . I 'll figure out something.